# enter button insert a new line instead of choosing an alternative

Tags: vim

Recently when I tried to use the ctrl+n or ctrl+p to auto-complete, when there are multiple alternatives, tapping the enter button will insert a new line instead choose the alternative I want.

This did not happen before, maybe because I installed too many plugins and caused the conflicts. It would be horrible to check all these plugins' shot cuts and find out the source. So mapping the built-in auto-complete to some other keys could be a solution, but I don't know how to do that.

This is not a big problem but really made coding not "smooth". Anybody has met this situation before and how did you deal with it.

Comment: do a `:verbose map <CR>` to see if `<CR>` is mapped to anything.

Comment: For insert mode, that would be `:verbose imap <CR>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You don't need to use `<cr>` to accept a match.

Snippet from the vim help `:h popupmenu-keys`

```
The behavior of the <Enter> key depends on the state you are in:
first state:      Use the text as it is and insert a line break.
second state:     Insert the currently selected match.
third state:      Use the text as it is and insert a line break.

In other words: If you used the cursor keys to select another entry in the
list of matches then the <Enter> key inserts that match.  If you typed
something else then <Enter> inserts a line break.
```

I would suggest you use `<c-n>` and `<c-p>` to switch to the correct mapping and then continue on with your typing. Typically this means I type a space or some other punctuation key and the menu closes. I never use `<cr>` to select a menu item. If however you really want to accept a match use `<c-y>`. Think "yes" to the selected menu item.

Comment: I did not know <c-y> can be used to select the menu item. Anyway, this resolved the occasional annoyance. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed a very similar problem caused by the vim-autoclose plugin by replacing it with the Auto-Pairs plugin.  I doubt that yours is exactly the same culprit but it's actually not too bad hunting down the guilty party if you use pathogen for your plugins - just move half of your plugins from `~/.vim/bundle` (or wherever they are) into a different folder, restart vim and test the autocompletion. If it works as expected, you know that one of the plugins you have moved out is responsible, so you can do the same again until you have narrowed it down.

Before that, you can also try running `vim -u NONE` which ignores your .vimrc file - it may be that you've snuck something in yourself and this is the fastest way to rule it out.

Good luck anyway.  This took me about ten minutes and after probably a year of occasional annoyance I wish I had taken the time earlier.